# get Powershell to put Start-Process ssh.exe in background

Tags: powershell, openssh

I'm using this powershell script below I pieced together with code I found online, and it works for the most part. It only needs to try two available ssh ports on a host using an if condition, then launch mstsc.exe after it succeeds. There are some nags I'd like to fix :

1. Why does the -NoNewWindow argument work in the first instance but not in the else block?
2. Why must I rely on Start-Sleep to run any lines after ssh.exe goes in the background. If I don't use Start-Sleep, it seems the mstsc.exe process launches too early or not at all since it is waiting for ssh.exe to finish. If you add -v to ssh, you will see it does finish with "forking to the background" which is finished but not technically.

Are there any Linux bash-like workarounds similar to using ampersand ?

Thanks!

```
$server = "152.306.2.20"
$port1 = 443
$port2 = 222
$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your username'
Write-Host "Trying $port1 ..."
$connection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient ($server, $port1)
if ($connection.Connected) {
    Write-Host "Port 222 available, establishing SSH connection with xrdp tunnel"
Start-Process -NoNewWindow ssh.exe -ArgumentList "-p $port1", '-Nf', "-l $user", '-L 3929:127.0.0.1:3929', "$server"
Start-Sleep -s 10
Write-Host "Opening remote desktop on localhost:3929"
Start-Sleep -s 2
Start-Process mstsc.exe -ArgumentList "/v:127.0.0.1:3929"
}
else {
Write-Host "Port 222 unavailable, establishing SSH connection with xrdp tunnel on alternate port"
Start-Process -NoNewWindow ssh.exe -ArgumentList "-p $port2", '-Nf', "-l $user", '-L 3929:127.0.0.1:3929', "$server"
Start-Sleep -s 10
Write-Host "Opening remote desktop on localhost:3929"
Start-Sleep -s 2
Start-Process mstsc.exe -ArgumentList "/v:127.0.0.1:3929"
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` why not just use `ssh.exe -p $port1 -Nf -l $user -L 3929:127.0.0.1:3929 $server`?

Comment: This is what I had originally, but after it went to the background it never went to the next line. I played around with -Wait and didn't get what I wanted so I thought I might have more control if I used Start-Process with all those arguments. It still doesn't work exactly the way I'd like, so I resorted to using the Start-Sleep to get to the mstsc.exe loading. OpenSSH says -N puts it in the background , but it never gets put into the background quite in the same way it would in Linux. Powershell still waits for the instruction to end before it goes to the next line and starts mstsc.exe.

Answer (score -1):

Woops question #1 was just because I was running from the Powershell editor, so it's not an issue. Question #2 is still unresolved.